# Sending AT command with USART2 to GSM modem[Embedded C]

Tags: c, embedded, stm32, keil

I am trying to send AT command thought USART1 from terminal and then using USART2 to the GSM modem[Terminal -> USART1 -> USART2 -> modem]. After sending AT command, modem do not send me back anything. What problem could it be? USART1 is working perfectly. I am using STM32 Nucleo and Keil uVision4.

Sending function

```
void send_usart2(char *msg){
send_usart1("USART2 sending...");   send_usart1("\r\n");
while (*msg){
    while(USART_GetFlagStatus(USART2, USART_FLAG_TXE) == RESET);
    USART_SendData(USART2, *msg++);
    }
    send_usart1("USART2 sending successful");   send_usart1("\r\n");
}
```

USART2 Handler

```
void USART2_IRQHandler(void){
int index = 0;
if(USART_GetITStatus(USART2, USART_IT_RXNE) != RESET){
    USART_ClearITPendingBit(USART2, USART_IT_RXNE);
    Received_values[index++] = USART_ReceiveData(USART2);
    }
}
```

Interrupt initialization

```
void InitInterrupt2(void) {
NVIC_InitTypeDef NVIC_InitStruct2;                             
NVIC_InitStruct2.NVIC_IRQChannel = USART2_IRQn;
NVIC_InitStruct2.NVIC_IRQChannelPreemptionPriority = 0;
NVIC_InitStruct2.NVIC_IRQChannelSubPriority = 0;           
NVIC_InitStruct2.NVIC_IRQChannelCmd = ENABLE;
NVIC_Init(&NVIC_InitStruct2);
}
```

UART initialization

```
void InitUART2(void) {      
GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStructure;
USART_InitTypeDef USART_InitStructure;
RCC_APB1PeriphClockCmd(RCC_APB1Periph_USART2, ENABLE);
RCC_APB2PeriphClockCmd(RCC_APB2Periph_GPIOA, ENABLE);

USART_InitStructure.USART_BaudRate = 115200; 
USART_InitStructure.USART_WordLength = USART_WordLength_8b ;
USART_InitStructure.USART_StopBits = USART_StopBits_1;
USART_InitStructure.USART_Parity = USART_Parity_No;
USART_InitStructure.USART_HardwareFlowControl = 
USART_HardwareFlowControl_None;
USART_InitStructure.USART_Mode = USART_Mode_Rx | USART_Mode_Tx;

USART_Init(USART2,&USART_InitStructure);         /* Configure USAR1 */                    
USART_ITConfig(USART2, USART_IT_RXNE, ENABLE);
USART_Cmd(USART2,ENABLE);                       /* Enable the USART1 */                                             

GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Mode = GPIO_Mode_AF_PP; 
GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Pin = GPIO_Pin_2;
GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Speed = GPIO_Speed_2MHz;
GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStructure);

GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Mode = GPIO_Mode_IN_FLOATING;
GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Pin = GPIO_Pin_3;
//GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Speed = GPIO_Speed_2MHz;
GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStructure);
}
```

And this looks like how i am sending it.

```
    .....
    send_usart2(Command_buffer);                
    send_usart1("Command: ");
    send_usart1(Command_buffer);
    send_usart1("\r\n");    
    memset(Command_buffer, NULL, sizeof(Command_buffer));
    os_dly_wait(500);
    send_usart1("Received values: ");
    send_usart1(Received_values);
    send_usart1("\r\n");
    memset(Received_values, NULL, sizeof(Received_values));
    .......
```

Comment: Do you not have `"\r\n"` in the outgoing command buffer to the modem?

Comment: i tried to add line send_usart2("\r\n"); after send_usart2(Command_buffer); line, but nothing happens.

Comment: What makes you think it is a software problem? Have you verified that data is present on the UART lines, all the way to the GSM module? Have you measured the baudrate with your oscilloscope?

Comment: Baud rate is given in manual. I know that Usart1 sends everything perfectly, but i am not sure if Usart2 does. Maybe you could suggest me how could i debugg Usart2?

Comment: First of all, remove the modem and connect
[Terminal1 --> USART1-->USART2-->Terminal2] and write a simple program for Rx and Tx of data for both USART i.e. a simple loopback program. Such that whatever you enter in Terminal1 window should appear on Terminal2 window and vice-versa.

Answer (score 0):

All i needed to configure this line form:

```
USART_HardwareFlowControl = USART_HardwareFlowControl_None;
```

To:

```
USART_HardwareFlowControl = USART_HardwareFlowControl_RTS;
```

This means that USART2 and Modem needs "handshake" connection type.